# Recursive Function of factorial

Tags: python-3.x

I can't understand logic of the last line of the below mentioned code. The code is a recursive function that gives you Factorial of a number. What does this(factorial(n-1))return each time?

```
def factorial(n): if n<=1: return 1 else: return n*factorial(n-1)
```

=================================================================

Comment: Weird thing: The function is called factorial, but returns a Fibonacci number. Anyway, you should try calling it on a small number like `2` or `3` and try to understand every execution step, including the call to `factorial(1)`.

Comment: @sammy It doesn't return fibonacci. It returns factorial

Comment: @sammy ... a fibonacci? how? for 5 it computes 5*(4*(3*(2*(1)))) ... not a fibonacci

Comment: Right. I'm just not sure the person asking the question understands that, because he mentioned Fibonacci.

Comment: sorry, its factorial i made a mistake! but  how does the function work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're calculating the factorial of something you are doing

```
1 * 2 * ... * n
```

Another way of representing this is

```
n * (n-1) * (n-2) * ... * 1
```

Or more simplified

```
n * (n-1) * ((n-1)-1) * ... * 1
```

Looking at that last bit you should be able to see that if the number is 1 the answer is 1. Otherwise it's the a number `n` times whatever the result of the factorial of `(n-1)` is.

That's exactly what this function does.

```py
def factorial(n): # declare the function
    if n<=1: 
        return 1 # if n is 1 or lower, the answer should be 1.
    else: 
        # otherwise, the answer is the result of n * (all these steps again for (n-1))
        return n*factorial(n-1)
```

---

Say you give `factorial(5)` what actually happens is

```
factorial(5) = 5 * factorial(4) 
    = 5 * (4 * factorial(3))
    = 5 * (4 * (3 * factorial(2)))
    = 5 * (4 * (3 * (2 * factorial(1))))
    = 5 * (4 * (3 * (2 * 1)))
```

Comment: my main question is that how does factorial(n-1) do (n-1)!?

Comment: Thanks for your good answer, i got it. and i think saving these different(n) and multiplying them is related to name space.